# Is it possible to Reparent standard objects

Tags: standard-objects

Is it possible to reparent the objects like Accountshare, AccountContactRole, Notes, Attchment, Event, Task..If yes how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty clear if you look at the describe information of the relationship field for each of these.

If the field in question has the `updateable` property, then yes...reparenting is likely possible.

Let's take `Attachment`.

Below, I went to `workbench.developerforce.com` and use the REST explorer to find the describe information using the Attachment describe URL

[image: Attachment describe]

If you expand the `fields` node and find `ParentId` you will see it is not updateable.

Here's the field:

[image]

Here's the updateable property:

[image]

If the describe says no, then absolutely, unequivocally, it is not able to be reparented. You must delete the existing record and add a new one in order to affect a pseudo "reparent" operation.

If you find one that can be reparented and you want to, you have some choices. DataLoader, or some other ETL/Data Management tool. Apex...probably with some kind of batch or scheduled process. Or you could use the import wizard and upsert over the existing records.

All of these are fairly well documented in many places, I suggest, if you're not a coder, the DataLoader/ETL/Data Management option, and do some searches on google for how to use those tools with Salesforce.